# Spring boot CLI settings proxy

Tags: spring, groovy, proxy, configure, command-line-interface

I installed Spring boot CLI on Windows 7 but, I use a proxy. I would like to know how to configure proxy with Spring boot. I set the variable JAVA_OPTS with -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL and
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber but I have received the message : 
"startup failed : General error during connection ..." after the command "spring run myscript.groovy". 
I use jdk 1.7.0_51 and spring boot 1.0.0RC3.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a known bug and there's [a fix on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/136#issuecomment-29453502)

Not sure if it's released yet tho...

Comment: Thank you but, I have just exports the java script in jar and replace the spring boot folder ?